# One lock that signals multiple threads when unlocked

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, locking, semaphore

Is there a way to implement a lock that is used by two components, when the first component consisting of multiple threads waits on a locked lock and the second component receives the lock and unlocks it which signals all the other threads that wait on it?

It needs to be cross-platform (and it will be implemented in C).

So is there a way to design such a thing?

Comment: What's the point of signalling those threads if they are still waiting?

Comment: Don't use a lock to do something other than lock. If you want to send a signal, use a semaphore, condition variable, or something else appropriate

Comment: These threads just wait till the second component is done working, and when it's done then they can continue working

Comment: How can I do it with a semaphore? maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I am not sure I understand the concept of "component consisting of multiple threads". Is this a thread group A that must be signaled as opposed to thread group B that must not?

Anyway I would direct you to condition variables as suggested above. If you are using POSIX then you can start with "pthread_cond_broadcast". Other libraries probably have equivalent methods.

Comment: Google "posix manual reset event".  Top hits are SO questions, answers are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one cross-platform solution that can be used on both POSIX and Windows systems, assuming those are your target systems.

On a POSIX system, use a condition variable and call [`pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) to unblock all waiting threads:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <pthread.h>
>
> int pthread_cond_broadcast(pthread_cond_t *cond);
> int pthread_cond_signal(pthread_cond_t *cond);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> These functions shall unblock threads blocked on a condition variable.
>
> **The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` function shall unblock all threads currently blocked on the specified condition variable `cond`**.
>
> ...

On Windows, [you can use WakeAllConditionVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Wake all threads waiting on the specified condition variable.**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> C++
>
> ```
> VOID WINAPI WakeAllConditionVariable(
>   _Inout_ PCONDITION_VARIABLE ConditionVariable
> );
> ```

It's not that hard to write your own cross-platform condition variable wrapper that wraps POSIX condition variables on POSIX systems and Windows condition variables on Windows systems.

Comment: Cool, that seems to solve my problem.. I'll have to also create a lock for each thread (that will do nothing) for this condition variable to work, right? and by the way is there a timeout mechanism on these condition variables (in POSIX?)

Comment: Nvm, I found the "pthread_cond_timedwait" which has a timeout on the condition variable and it seems that I'll still have to use a lock that will do nothing.

Comment: The mutex required by a POSIX condition variable doesn't "do nothing".  There are many examples of how to use POSIX condition variables:  https://www.google.com/search?q=pthread_cond_wait+example